# C# Settings Rembering Settings

Tags: c#, settings

How do I get my program to remember the users settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

- write the settings to a file
- Create setting in VS with Project->Properties->Settings... then by using

  Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName = "something"; // Set setting

  this.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName; // Use setting

Comment: If you want the settings to persist between application sessions then you will also need to save them: 

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for [UserScopedSettingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.userscopedsettingattribute.aspx)